# the commands of my discord bot is not working except 1

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
import random
from random import randint
from replit import db
from discord.ext import commands


client = discord.Client()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.') 

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'{client.user.name} működik!')   
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='egy bot vagyok'))

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()   
    await member.dm_channel.send(
        f' {member.name}, itt van!'
    )


@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
    print(f'haha')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('ping'):
        await message.channel.send("pong")

    if message.content.startswith("shrug"):
        await message.channel.send('¯\_(ツ)_/¯')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('.pic'):
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('combo-0.png'))


token = os.environ.get("secret")
client.run(token)
```

im a beginner in discord bot programming
this is my whole code for my discord bot and all of the commands are not working except one

te **.pic** command

all of the commands worked until now and i dont know why they dont work

if i would get some help i would be happy :D
(sorry for my bad english, english isnt my first language)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple `on_message` events, only the last one will be registered. You have to combine them into one

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('ping'):
        await message.channel.send("pong")

    if message.content.startswith("shrug"):
        await message.channel.send('¯\_(ツ)_/¯')

    if message.content.startswith('.pic'):
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('combo-0.png'))
```

Comment: If I may add to this correct answer, think about assigning a variable.  If you type `i=7` and then `i=9`, you expect `i` to end up as 9.  Same thing here.  The second `on_message` simply erases the first definition.

Comment: the bot command doesnt work, it doesnt show errors and the bot wont respond

Comment: @bndsz See the other answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix up the `discord.Client()` and `commands.Bot` clients like this.

`commands.Bot` is a subclass of `discord.Client`, so you should be able to do everything that you could do with `discord.Client()` with `commands.Bot()`

```py
bot = commands.Bot('!')
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ready')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')
```

For help with the rewrite `discord.ext.commands`, there are a butt ton of tutorials on the internet.